# Question about sequences and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a short question: Can a monotone strictly increasing sequence which is bounded converge? I thought yes since it would converge, but never be exactly the limit, so s_n+1>s_n for all n belongs to N. 
But I did just read a proof of someone that says this is a contradiction. 
Am I wrong?

Comment: A monotone increasing bounded above sequence *always* converges the supremum of the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strictly increasing sequence converges [to a finite limit] iff it’s bounded. Otherwise it diverges to $\infty$.
It‘s called the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).
It also follows that if $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing then

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sup \{ a_n : n\in \Bbb N \}$$

and if it‘s strictly decreasing
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \inf \{ a_n : n\in \Bbb N \}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

One way to prove it would be to use the least upper bound property to show a supremum exist, and use the definition to show that the sequence converge to that supremum.

Comment: How is the definition in your hyperlink logically equivalent to the one provided on page 78 in this here link: http://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf (when you're scrolling or typing in the page number it's actually on page 93)

Comment: The form is exactly stated in [Theorem 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_3) in that page.